# z score on Wilcoxon signed ranks test?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I was wondering if anyone might have some answers to a question regarding running a Wilcoxon signed rank test in R.

When looking up how to report our scores, it tells us to report a Z score. However, running a Wilcoxon signed rank test in R produces a V, not a Z, score.

Are these two interchangeable? Or different scores? If so, how would I calculate z?

Comment: Are you talking about convergence to the normal distirubtion?

Comment: Should this have the `self-study` tag?

Comment: This discussion may be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330129/how-to-get-the-z-score-in-wilcox-test-in-r

Answer (score 8):

Given the number of elements in your samples (and the number of ties in them), you can transform one (the test stat, say in your case the $V$ stat though as I show below, this will also work for the $W$ stat) to the other (the corresponding z score) fairly easily.

The formula's for the W and V stats are widely available ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Test_procedure) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction)). In fact, these computations are already done in the R code when `exact = FALSE` --to compute the p-val-- they are just not exported.

To have R export these statistics, copy to the source [code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R) to an R script.

On line 397-403 you see:

```
    RVAL <- list(statistic = STATISTIC,
                 parameter = NULL,
                 p.value = as.numeric(PVAL),
                 null.value = mu,
                 alternative = alternative,
                 method = METHOD,
data.name = DNAME)
```

Change it to:

```
    RVAL <- list(statistic = STATISTIC,
                 parameter = NULL,
                 p.value = as.numeric(PVAL),
                 null.value = mu,
                 alternative = alternative,
                 method = METHOD,
                 z_val = z,
data.name = DNAME)
```

Save the function under a different name. Say `wilcox_test`. Then, whenever the $z$ score is available (when `exact = FALSE`), `wilcox_test` will return it. Example;

```
set.seed(123);
wilcox_test(runif(4000), rnorm(100), exact = FALSE)$z_val
      W 
8.77776
```

or:

```
 set.seed(123);
wilcox_test(runif(4000), exact = FALSE)$z_val
       V 
54.77567
```

Answer (score 6):

See Section 7.2 of [BBR](http://www.fharrell.com/doc/bbr.pdf) which discusses a simple, accurate $z$ test statistic for the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.  $z$ equals the sum of signed ranks divided by the square root of the sum of their squares.  This handles ties well also.

Comment: +1. Did not know of that simple correction for the signed rank test.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not interchangeable. The $V$ in Wilcoxon signed test from R wilcox test is "**[the sum of ranks assigned to the differences with positive sign](https://www.r-bloggers.com/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test/)**".

Let me show you by using ZeaMays data.

First we do the Wilcoxon signed test using wilcox.test funciton.

```
 install.packages("HistData")
 library(HistData)
 data(ZeaMays)
 head(ZeaMays)
 wilcox.test(ZeaMays$cross, ZeaMays$self, paired=TRUE)
```

The results are:

```
   # Wilcoxon signed rank test
   # data:  ZeaMays$cross and ZeaMays$self
   # V = 96, p-value = 0.04126
   # alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Now let us calculate V by hand

```
 diff<-ZeaMays$cross-ZeaMays$self #calculate paired difference
 diff
 rank_d<-rank(abs(diff))*sign(diff) #rank the difference and assign the sign
```

Next we calculate "**the sum of ranks assigned to the differences with positive sign"**. i.e $V$

```
p_rank<-c() #postive ranks only
for (i in 1:15){
if (rank_d[i]>0){
p_rank[i]=rank_d[i]}
}
V<-sum(p_rank,na.rm=TRUE)
V
#[1] 96
```

You can see $V=96$ which is exactly the same as the $V$ of the wilcox.test.

Next what is $Z$ score?

$E_{H_0}(V)=\frac{n(n+1)}{4} =\frac{15\times 16}{4}=60$

$Var_{H_0}(V)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}=\frac{15\times 16\times 31}{24}$

and $Z=\frac{V-E(V)}{\sqrt{Var(V)}}\sim N(0,1)$

i.e the $Z$  can be shown converge to standard normal.

Therefore your $z$ score is:$\frac{96-60}{\sqrt{\frac{15\times 16\times31}{24}}}=2.044663$

Which correspond the two sided p value 0.04088813

```
  2*(1-pnorm(z,0,1))
  #p=0.04088813$
```

The p value is a little different, maybe because wilcox.test used some correction.

Comment: mmh. Using  `2*(1-pnorm(2.016265,0,1))` gives the same p-val as the default `wilcox.test` function in `R`: 
 `0.04377227`. `2.016265` in the line above is the value of the z-stat  given by the modified function in my answer. Are you sure you are dealing with ties in a defensible way? Your data contains ties and your answer is not adjusting for them.

Comment: If there are ties, I probably just average them then use the average as the rank for all of them. If we use continuous correction, i.e use 95.5 instead of 96.  the z will be 2.016265 which will be the same as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following to obtain the Z-score when doing a Wilcoxon signed rank test.

```
test<-wilcox.test(mtdata$x, mydata$y, paired=TRUE, exact=TRUE) 

print(test) # get the results of the Wilcoxon signed rank test

Zstat<-qnorm(test$p.value/2)  # obtain the Z-score 
abs(Zstat)/sqrt(20)
```

Comment: One limitation to this approach is that the z value will not be signed.  That is, usually with a two-sample test the reported z value will be negative if the second group has higher values.  One could, for example, look at the sign of Cliff's delta and then apply that sign to the z value obtained with this method.  Likewise, if this value is used to compute an *r* effect size, this is often signed as well. When reporting signed values, one should be careful about which group the software is treating as the first group.

Comment: There's some more discussion at the following link, including the option to use the *coin* package for the test and z value, or a function I added (with all the caveats there!) in the *rcompanion* package. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330129/how-to-get-the-z-score-in-wilcox-test-in-r