# How to get the z- score in Wilcox test in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, z-score

Using the  wilcox.test() function in R, I get the p-value. I want to report the z-score for the test.

How can i get the z-score for wilcox test in R?

Comment: The R code never stores the z-score, but you can simply use qnorm() to convert back from p-value to the equivalent z-score.

Comment: @sheetal_158 The test being performed is the *Wilcoxon* test (even though R calls it `wilcox`, much to my annoyance. The (needless) abbreviation is actively misleading).

Comment: Another approach I've seen is using the wilcox_test function in the coin package.  The statistic it returns is supposedly the z statistic of interest.

Comment: @GordonSmyth , from the examples I'm reading online, it looks like the code for the *qnorm* function in the Mann-Whitney case uses the p-value from the test, but for the paired rank sum (`paired=T`) version of the test, that the p-value is divided by 2 when passed to the *qnorm* function.  Can you confirm that this makes sense?

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing, the comments pretty much answer the question, but I'll put them in answer form, so that the code can be shown explicitly.

The following demonstrates the two techniques I've seen commonly used.  I can't vouch for either of them.

The first uses the *wilcox_test* function in the *coin* package.  The statistics reported here are called *Z* and *r*.

The second uses the *wilcox.test* function and derives *Z* from invoking the *qnorm* function.  The statistics reported here are called *Za* and *ra*.

*r* is sometimes calculated as an effect size for the Mann-Whitney test.  It is included here because calculating *r* is one of the reasons why people want to extract the *Z* value.

You'll note that the *Z* values differ between the two techniques.

```
if(!require(coin)){install.packages("coin")}

set.seed(169)

n = 16

N = n + n

A = runif(n,1,10)
B = A + 5 + rnorm(n,0,4)

Group = factor(c(rep("A", length(A)), rep("B", length(B))))
Y = c(A,B)

boxplot(Y ~ Group)

library(coin)

MW = wilcox_test(Y ~ Group)
MW

Z = as.numeric(statistic(MW, type="standardized"))
names(Z) = "Z"

Z

   ###         Z 
   ### -4.258848 

MWa = wilcox.test(Y ~ Group, exact=FALSE)

MWa

Za = qnorm(MWa$p.value/2)

Za

   ### [1] -4.240003

r = abs(Z)/sqrt(N)
names(r) = "r"

r

   ###        r 
   ### 0.752865

ra = abs(Za)/sqrt(N)
names(ra) = "ra"

ra

   ###        ra 
   ### 0.7495338
```

Sources of interest:
[Grokbase](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/05be9vbd31/r-effect-sizes-for-wilcoxon-tests)

Comment: I also added a [function in the *rcompanion* package](https://rdrr.io/cran/rcompanion/man/wilcoxonZ.html) that reports the z score using the methods from `wilcox.test`.  This helps to ensure that the reported z value reflects the options of how the test was run with *wilcox.test*.  It also returns a signed value, so that  the z will be negative if the second group has larger values.

Comment: I assume the '/2' in 'Za = qnorm(MWa$p.value/2)' is because the test was two-sided and would be excluded for a one-sided test?

Comment: Yes, the *2* is because it's a two-sided test.  For a one-sided test, you exclude the *2*, but  you may need to be careful about the  sign of the resulting *z* value, if you care about that.  Adding a `lower.tail=FALSE` will be warranted in some cases.

Comment: Here's a quick little example.  The *z* value is -1.81.  The *p* value results for `alternative=` `two.sided`, `greater`, and `less` are all converted back to a *z* value.  Note to pay attention to the sign of the calculated *z* value.  `A = c(1,2,3,4,6,7); B = c(5,8,9); library(rcompanion); wilcox.test(A, B, alternative="two.sided", exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE); wilcox.test(A, B, alternative="less", exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE); wilcox.test(A, B, alternative="greater", exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE); wilcoxonZ(A,B); qnorm(0.0707/2); qnorm(0.03535); qnorm(0.9646, lower.tail=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my case, I just needed 4 values, so I quickly checked the sign by hand.

Comment: @SalMangiafico does the Z statistic returned correct the variance for ties? It does not seem to be the case (or I am doing the hand calculations wrong)

Comment: @JPMD, This might be a discussion for chat or email....  Two-sample, One-sample, or paired test ?  Is *z* value from *wilcox_test(*), *wilcoxonR ()*, or from the *p* value ?

Comment: Sorry, two-sample ... as in here `rcompanion::wilcoxonZ(x=item1, y=item2,correct = TRUE)`... You do the continuity correction (subtract 0.5 if $U \ge \mu_U$, sum 0.5 otherwise...

item1 <- c(1,5,3,4,4,2,3,2)
item2 <- c(1,4,5,4,3,1)

Comment: P.S. WilcoxonZ does indeed the correction for ties in the variance!

Comment: Yes, the *wilcoxonZ()* function extracts the *z* value from the native *wilcox.test()* function, so the results should match the *p*-value from that function.  e.g. `A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); B = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); rcompanion::wilcoxonZ(A, B, correct = TRUE, digits=6); wilcox.test(A, B, correct=TRUE); pnorm(-1.42408)*2`

Comment: Can you point to a reference/formula for the Continuity correction in `wilcox.test()`? I get diferent values if I use $Z=(|U-\mu_U|-0.5)/\sigma_U$...

Comment: You can see what `wilcox.test()` is doing here:. [github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R). See, `if(correct)` past line 245 for the 2-sample case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145135/discussion-between-jpmd-and-sal-mangiafico).